# Smooth scroll without the use of jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coding up a page where I only want to use raw JavaScript code for UI without any interference of plugins or frameworks.

And now I'm struggling with finding a way to scroll over the page smoothly without jQuery.

Comment: The same way jQuery would do it.  Break the animation up into a series of very small steps, use an interval timer at a small interval to perform each of these steps in turn until they are done.

Comment: I thought of this solution at the beginning and the only point I missed is actually in Kamal's link below, which is how to calculate the Y-positions of objects. Thanks tvanfosson :)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer on [smooth scrolling with plain js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722497/scroll-smoothly-to-specific-element-on-page/17731750#17731750)

Comment: This is similar to one of my questions. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598955/create-a-nice-scrolling-sliding-effect-with-js/40599086#40599086.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this [smooth scrolling demo](http://web.archive.org/web/20140213105950/http://itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript), or an algorithm like:

1. Get the current top location using `self.pageYOffset`
2. Get the position of element till where you want to scroll to: `element.offsetTop`
3. Do a for loop to reach there, which will be quite fast or use a timer to do smooth scroll till that position using `window.scrollTo`

---

See also the [other popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808153/59087) to this question.

---

Andrew Johnson's original code:

```
function currentYPosition() {
    // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
    // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
    if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
        return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
    if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
    return 0;
}


function elmYPosition(eID) {
    var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
    var y = elm.offsetTop;
    var node = elm;
    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
        node = node.offsetParent;
        y += node.offsetTop;
    } return y;
}


function smoothScroll(eID) {
    var startY = currentYPosition();
    var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
    var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
    if (distance < 100) {
        scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
    }
    var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
    if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
    var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
    var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
    var timer = 0;
    if (stopY > startY) {
        for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
        } return;
    }
    for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
        leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
    }
}
```

---

Related links:

- https://www.sitepoint.com/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript/
- https://github.com/zengabor/zenscroll/blob/dist/zenscroll.js
- https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll/blob/master/src/js/smooth-scroll.js
- https://github.com/alicelieutier/smoothScroll/blob/master/smoothscroll.js

Comment: Good outline but please don't create a string to execute for the timeout, go ahead and create an anonymous function that calls the actual function.

Comment: @nness it's a shame. I really wanted to see the code.

Answer (score 50):

Native browser smooth scrolling in JavaScript is like this:

```
// scroll to specific values,
// same as window.scroll() method.
// for scrolling a particular distance, use window.scrollBy().
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // negative value acceptable
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// scroll to a certain element
document.querySelector('.hello').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Comment: can you put on demo link

Comment: @Vishu Rana, behavior support only goes to firefox as described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: @EvandroCavalcateSantos: not anymore! ;-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: This modern standard is nice and readable, but needs a `speed` option. Current scrolling speed is too slow for flow.

Comment: I created a demo with speed: https://codepen.io/Niekes/pen/poEqaBW You can control the speed by changing the "duration" variable.

Answer (score 25):

### Algorithm

Scrolling an element requires changing its `scrollTop` value over time. For a given point in time, calculate a new `scrollTop` value. To animate smoothly, interpolate using a [smooth-step algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep).

Calculate `scrollTop` as follows:

```
var point = smooth_step(start_time, end_time, now);
var scrollTop = Math.round(start_top + (distance * point));
```

Where:

- `start_time` is the time the animation started;
- `end_time` is when the animation will end `(start_time + duration)`;
- `start_top` is the `scrollTop` value at the beginning; and
- `distance` is the difference between the desired end value and the start value `(target - start_top)`.

A robust solution should detect when animating is interrupted, and more. Read my post about [Smooth Scrolling without jQuery](https://coderwall.com/p/hujlhg) for details.

### Demo

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0uwg96sh/).

### Implementation

The code:

```
/**
    Smoothly scroll element to the given target (element.scrollTop)
    for the given duration

    Returns a promise that's fulfilled when done, or rejected if
    interrupted
 */
var smooth_scroll_to = function(element, target, duration) {
    target = Math.round(target);
    duration = Math.round(duration);
    if (duration < 0) {
        return Promise.reject("bad duration");
    }
    if (duration === 0) {
        element.scrollTop = target;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    var start_time = Date.now();
    var end_time = start_time + duration;

    var start_top = element.scrollTop;
    var distance = target - start_top;

    // based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep
    var smooth_step = function(start, end, point) {
        if(point <= start) { return 0; }
        if(point >= end) { return 1; }
        var x = (point - start) / (end - start); // interpolation
        return x*x*(3 - 2*x);
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // This is to keep track of where the element's scrollTop is
        // supposed to be, based on what we're doing
        var previous_top = element.scrollTop;

        // This is like a think function from a game loop
        var scroll_frame = function() {
            if(element.scrollTop != previous_top) {
                reject("interrupted");
                return;
            }

            // set the scrollTop for this frame
            var now = Date.now();
            var point = smooth_step(start_time, end_time, now);
            var frameTop = Math.round(start_top + (distance * point));
            element.scrollTop = frameTop;

            // check if we're done!
            if(now >= end_time) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }

            // If we were supposed to scroll but didn't, then we
            // probably hit the limit, so consider it done; not
            // interrupted.
            if(element.scrollTop === previous_top
                && element.scrollTop !== frameTop) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            previous_top = element.scrollTop;

            // schedule next frame for execution
            setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
        }

        // boostrap the animation process
        setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: This seems like a really good solution. But how can you implement it on window object instead of an element like you have in your Fiddle?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Had to use `pageYOffset` and `scrollTo()` on `element` instead of `scrollTop`.

Comment: Can you explain what does this basically do?
return x*x*(3 - 2*x);

I read the wiki but didn't understand. Is this easing function? If yes how can I get linear easing out of this?

Comment: @Harry linear means no easing, so just `return x` instead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the new  **Scroll Behaviour** CSS Property.

for example, add the below line to your CSS.

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

and this will result in a native smooth scrolling feature.

see [demo here](https://shakiltech.com)

All modern browsers support the **scroll-behavior** property.

[Read More about Scroll behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 6):

I've made an example without jQuery here : http://codepen.io/sorinnn/pen/ovzdq

```
/**
    by Nemes Ioan Sorin - not an jQuery big fan 
    therefore this script is for those who love the old clean coding style  
    @id = the id of the element who need to bring  into view

    Note : this demo scrolls about 12.700 pixels from Link1 to Link3
*/
(function()
{
      window.setTimeout = window.setTimeout; //
})();

      var smoothScr = {
      iterr : 30, // set timeout miliseconds ..decreased with 1ms for each iteration
        tm : null, //timeout local variable
      stopShow: function()
      {
        clearTimeout(this.tm); // stopp the timeout
        this.iterr = 30; // reset milisec iterator to original value
      },
      getRealTop : function (el) // helper function instead of jQuery
      {
        var elm = el; 
        var realTop = 0;
        do
        {
          realTop += elm.offsetTop;
          elm = elm.offsetParent;
        }
        while(elm);
        return realTop;
      },
      getPageScroll : function()  // helper function instead of jQuery
      {
        var pgYoff = window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        return pgYoff;
      },
      anim : function (id) // the main func
      {
        this.stopShow(); // for click on another button or link
        var eOff, pOff, tOff, scrVal, pos, dir, step;

        eOff = document.getElementById(id).offsetTop; // element offsetTop

        tOff =  this.getRealTop(document.getElementById(id).parentNode); // terminus point 

        pOff = this.getPageScroll(); // page offsetTop

        if (pOff === null || isNaN(pOff) || pOff === 'undefined') pOff = 0;

        scrVal = eOff - pOff; // actual scroll value;

        if (scrVal > tOff) 
        {
          pos = (eOff - tOff - pOff); 
          dir = 1;
        }
        if (scrVal < tOff)
        {
          pos = (pOff + tOff) - eOff;
          dir = -1; 
        }
        if(scrVal !== tOff) 
        {
          step = ~~((pos / 4) +1) * dir;

          if(this.iterr > 1) this.iterr -= 1; 
          else this.itter = 0; // decrease the timeout timer value but not below 0
          window.scrollBy(0, step);
          this.tm = window.setTimeout(function()
          {
             smoothScr.anim(id);  
          }, this.iterr); 
        }  
        if(scrVal === tOff) 
        { 
          this.stopShow(); // reset function values
          return;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippits or description of how it works here. Your answer should be able to make sense without my needing to click anything. Thank you!

Comment: thanks - but no - codeopen is made for sharing examples - here is not the right place to put all css / js / html code - util stackoverflow will add the necessary bits - most peoples will send you to codepen / jsfiddle / or elsewhere ..

Comment: Here's some of the conversation on why we ask for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890

Comment: I don't understand the need of `window.setTimeout = window.setTimeout;`

Answer (score 6):

Modern browsers has support for CSS "scroll-behavior: smooth" property. So, we even don't need any Javascript at all for this. Just add this for the "html" element, and use usual anchors and links.
[scroll-behavior MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

Comment: Both Edge and Safari are not supporting this property yet. I hope they will soon.

Comment: It doesn't work well.. even in Firefox. So it is not a solution.

Comment: has only a single speed. it sucks.

Answer (score 4):

I recently set out to solve this problem in a situation where jQuery wasn't an option, so I'm logging my solution here just for posterity.

```
var scroll = (function() {

    var elementPosition = function(a) {
        return function() {
            return a.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        };
    };

    var scrolling = function( elementID ) {

        var el = document.getElementById( elementID ),
            elPos = elementPosition( el ),
            duration = 400,
            increment = Math.round( Math.abs( elPos() )/40 ),
            time = Math.round( duration/increment ),
            prev = 0,
            E;

        function scroller() {
            E = elPos();

            if (E === prev) {
                return;
            } else {
                prev = E;
            }

            increment = (E > -20 && E < 20) ? ((E > - 5 && E < 5) ? 1 : 5) : increment;

            if (E > 1 || E < -1) {

                if (E < 0) {
                    window.scrollBy( 0,-increment );
                } else {
                    window.scrollBy( 0,increment );
                }

                setTimeout(scroller, time);

            } else {

                el.scrollTo( 0,0 );

            }
        }

        scroller();
    };

    return {
        To: scrolling
    }

})();

/* usage */
scroll.To('elementID');
```

The `scroll()` function uses the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647397/4746328) to pass the target element's id to its `scrolling()` function, via `scroll.To('id')`, which sets the values used by the `scroller()` function.

**Breakdown**

In `scrolling()`:

- `el` :  the target DOM object
- `elPos` :  returns a function via `elememtPosition()` which gives the position of the target element relative to the top of the page each time it's called.
- `duration` :  transition time in milliseconds.
- `increment` :  divides the starting position of the target element into 40 steps.
- `time` :  sets the timing of each step.
- `prev` :  the target element's previous position in `scroller()`.
- `E` : holds the target element's position in `scroller()`.

The actual work is done by the `scroller()` function which continues to call itself (via `setTimeout()`) until the target element is at the top of the page or the page can scroll no more.

Each time `scroller()` is called it checks the current position of the target element (held in variable `E`) and if that is `> 1` OR `< -1` and if the page is still scrollable shifts the window by `increment` pixels - up or down depending if `E` is a positive or negative value.  When `E` is neither `> 1` OR `< -1`, or `E` === `prev` the function stops.  I added the `DOMElement.scrollTo()` method on completion just to make sure the target element was bang on the top of the window (not that you'd notice it being out by a fraction of a pixel!).

The `if` statement on line 2 of `scroller()` checks to see if the page is scrolling  (in cases where the target might be towards the bottom of the page and the page can scroll no further) by checking `E` against its previous position (`prev`).

The ternary condition below it reduce the `increment` value as `E` approaches zero.  This stops the page overshooting one way and then bouncing back to overshoot the other, and then bouncing back to overshoot the other again, ping-pong style, to infinity and beyond.

If your page is more that c.4000px high you might want to increase the values in the ternary expression's first condition (here at +/-20) and/or the divisor which sets the `increment` value (here at 40).

Playing about with `duration`, the divisor which sets `increment`, and the values in the ternary condition of `scroller()` should allow you to tailor the function to suit your page.

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BnPck/rdetuhyL/1/)
- *N.B.Tested in up-to-date versions of Firefox and Chrome on Lubuntu, and Firefox, Chrome and IE on Windows8.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
document.querySelector('your-element').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
```

If you want to scroll top the top of the page, you can just place an empty element in the top, and smooth scroll to that one.

Answer (score 2):

I've made something like this.
I have no idea if its working in IE8.
Tested in IE9, Mozilla, Chrome, Edge.

```
function scroll(toElement, speed) {
  var windowObject = window;
  var windowPos = windowObject.pageYOffset;
  var pointer = toElement.getAttribute('href').slice(1);
  var elem = document.getElementById(pointer);
  var elemOffset = elem.offsetTop;

  var counter = setInterval(function() {
    windowPos;

    if (windowPos > elemOffset) { // from bottom to top
      windowObject.scrollTo(0, windowPos);
      windowPos -= speed;

      if (windowPos <= elemOffset) { // scrolling until elemOffset is higher than scrollbar position, cancel interval and set scrollbar to element position
        clearInterval(counter);
        windowObject.scrollTo(0, elemOffset);
      }
    } else { // from top to bottom
      windowObject.scrollTo(0, windowPos);
      windowPos += speed;

      if (windowPos >= elemOffset) { // scroll until scrollbar is lower than element, cancel interval and set scrollbar to element position
        clearInterval(counter);
        windowObject.scrollTo(0, elemOffset);
      }
    }

  }, 1);
}

//call example

var navPointer = document.getElementsByClassName('nav__anchor');

for (i = 0; i < navPointer.length; i++) {
  navPointer[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    scroll(this, 18);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

**Description**

- `pointer`—get element and chceck if it has attribute "href" if yes,
  get rid of "#"
- `elem`—pointer variable without "#"
- `elemOffset`—offset of "scroll to" element from the top of the page

Answer (score 1):

With using the following smooth scrolling is working fine:

```html
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var set = 0;

function animatescroll(x, y) {
    if (set == 0) {
        var val72 = 0;
        var val73 = 0;
        var setin = 0;
        set = 1;

        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (setin == 0) {
                val72++;
                val73 += x / 1000;
                if (val72 == 1000) {
                    val73 = 0;
                    interval = clearInterval(interval);
                }
                document.getElementById(y).scrollTop = val73;
            }
        }, 1);
    }
}
</script>
```

**x** = scrollTop
**y** = id of the div that is used to scroll

**Note:** 
For making the body to scroll give the body an ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different methods for smooth scrolling in JavaScript. The most common ones are listed below.

---

To scroll to a certain position in an exact amount of time, [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) can be put to use, calculating the appropriate current position each time. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) can be used to a similar effect when `requestAnimationFrame` is not supported. (To scroll to a specific element with the function below, just set the position to `element.offsetTop`.)

```js
/*
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

Demo:

```js
/*
   @param time: the exact amount of time the scrolling will take (in milliseconds)
   @param pos: the y-position to scroll to (in pixels)
*/
function scrollToSmoothly(pos, time) {
    var currentPos = window.pageYOffset;
    var start = null;
    if(time == null) time = 500;
    pos = +pos, time = +time;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(currentTime) {
        start = !start ? currentTime : start;
        var progress = currentTime - start;
        if (currentPos < pos) {
            window.scrollTo(0, ((pos - currentPos) * progress / time) + currentPos);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, currentPos - ((currentPos - pos) * progress / time));
        }
        if (progress < time) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        } else {
            window.scrollTo(0, pos);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 300)">
Scroll To Div (300ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 200)">
Scroll To Div (200ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 100)">
Scroll To Div (100ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 50)">
Scroll To Div (50ms)
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.querySelector('div').offsetTop, 1000)">
Scroll To Div (1000ms)
</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">
DIV<p/>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(0, 500)">
Back To Top
</button>
<button onClick="scrollToSmoothly(document.body.scrollHeight)">
Scroll To Bottom
</button>
</div>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">
</div>
<button style="margin-top: 100px;" onClick="scrollToSmoothly(500, 3000)">
Scroll To y-position 500px (3000ms)
</button>
```

For more complex cases, the [SmoothScroll.js library](https://github.com/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll) can be used, which handles smooth scrolling both vertically and horizontally, scrolling inside other container elements, different easing behaviors, scrolling relatively from the current position, and more.

```js
var easings = document.getElementById("easings");
for(var key in smoothScroll.easing){
    if(smoothScroll.easing.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = option.value = key;
        easings.add(option);
    }
}
document.getElementById('to-bottom').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    smoothScroll({yPos: 'end', easing: easings.value, duration: 2000});
});
document.getElementById('to-top').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    smoothScroll({yPos: 'start', easing: easings.value, duration: 2000});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LieutenantPeacock/SmoothScroll@1.2.0/src/smoothscroll.min.js" integrity="sha384-UdJHYJK9eDBy7vML0TvJGlCpvrJhCuOPGTc7tHbA+jHEgCgjWpPbmMvmd/2bzdXU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Taken from one of the library examples -->
Easing: <select id="easings"></select>
<button id="to-bottom">Scroll To Bottom</button>
<br>
<button id="to-top" style="margin-top: 5000px;">Scroll To Top</button>
```

Alternatively, you can pass an options object to [`window.scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scroll) which scrolls to a specific x and y position and [`window.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/scrollBy) which scrolls a certain amount from the current position:

```
// Scroll to specific values
// scrollTo is the same
window.scroll({
  top: 2500, 
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});

// Scroll certain amounts from current position 
window.scrollBy({ 
  top: 100, // could be negative value
  left: 0, 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
var elem = document.querySelector("div");
window.scroll({
      top: elem.offsetTop, 
      left: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
});
}
</script>
```

If you only need to scroll to an element, not a specific position in the document, you can use [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) with `behavior` set to `smooth`.

```
document.getElementById("elemID").scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});
```

Demo:

```html
<button onClick="scrollToDiv()">Scroll To Element</button>
<div id="myDiv" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
<script>
function scrollToDiv(){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").scrollIntoView({ 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
   });
}
</script>
```

Modern browsers support the [`scroll-behavior` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior), which can be used to make scrolling in the document smooth (without the need for JavaScript).  Anchor tags can be used for this by giving the anchor tag a `href` of `#` plus the `id` of the element to scroll to). You can also set the `scroll-behavior` property for a specific container like a `div` to make its contents scroll smoothly.

Demo:

```css
html, body{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<a href="#elem">Scroll To Element</a>
<div id="elem" style="margin: 500px 0px;">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Works in most browsers

```
document.getElementById("scrollHere").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```js
document.getElementById("end").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

```css
body {margin: 0px; display: block; height: 100%; background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);}
.start {display: block; margin: 100px 10px 1000px 0px;}
.end {display: block; margin: 0px 0px 100px 0px;}
```

```html
<div class="start">Start</div>
<div class="end" id="end">End</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my variation:

```
let MenuItem = function ( _menuItem ) {

    // I had a sticky header, so its height had to be taken into account when scrolling
    let _header = document.querySelector('.site-header');

    let _scrollToBlock = function( e, menuItem ) {

            let id = menuItem.getAttribute('href'), // the href attribute stores the id of the block to which the scroll will be
                headerHeight = _header.offsetHeight; // determine the height of the header
            id = id.replace(/#/, ''); // remove the # sign from the id block
            let elem = document.getElementById( id ), // define the element to which we will scroll
                top = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY - headerHeight; // determine the height of the scroll
            window.scroll({
                top: top,
                left: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            });

        },
        _addEvents = function() {

            _menuItem.addEventListener('click', function (e){
                e.preventDefault(); // Disable redirect on click
                _scrollToBlock(e, _menuItem);
            });

        },
        _init = function() {
            _addEvents();
        };

    _init();

};

// Initialize the class MenuItem to all links with class .menu__item
document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item').forEach( function(item) {
    new MenuItem(item);
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the code that worked for me.

```
`$('a[href*="#"]')

    .not('[href="#"]')
    .not('[href="#0"]')
    .click(function(event) {
     if (
       location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
       &&
       location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {

  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
  if (target.length) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000, function() {

      var $target = $(target);
      $target.focus();
      if ($target.is(":focus")) { 
        return false;
      } else {
        $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); 
        $target.focus(); 
      };
    });
    }
   }
  });
```

`

Comment: can you explain a little more about what your code does?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, thank you for answering but the question was about not using jquery.