# Html select option onclick not working in Chrome & may be another

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want that html select option scroll down to the `div` using `div` ID and On-click Html attribute and JavaScript (`document.getElementById`). but On-click attribute not working in select option. if it is not possible to use on-click attribute. Then show me another way to do this.

```html
<select>
<option>1111111</option>
<option>2222222</option>
<option onclick="document.getElementById('divid1').scrollIntoView();">Scroll down to div id</option>
<option>4444444</option>
<option>5555555</option>
<option>6666666</option>
</select>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='divid1'>scroll</div>
```

Hoping for Answer

Comment: Shouldn't id be: divid11? (you are missing one digit at the end). And, after that fix - your code works for me, at least in firefox...

Comment: That will not solve the OP's issue though, just a type-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in Chrome, too: *(use onchange event handler, and pass selected value to function)*

HTML:

```
<select onchange="scroll_to(this.value);">
<option>1111111</option>
<option>2222222</option>
<option >Scroll down to div id</option>
<option>4444444</option>
<option>5555555</option>
<option>6666666</option>
</select>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='divid11'>scroll</div>
```

Javascript:

```
  function scroll_to(val) {
     if(val== "Scroll down to div id")  
        document.getElementById('divid11').scrollIntoView();
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uya2skz5/

Btw, your first code with onclick handler, worked fine in Firefox.

Comment: @MakashifFaryad  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery... you got some solutions here (easier with jQuery)

Comment: plz add smooth scroll in **JsFiddle** Above in your answer.