# Gradually scroll on mousedown until mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make the viewport scroll down gradually while the mouse button is pressed down over a `position: fixed` element?

Comment: When scrolling, won't the mouse cursor come off the element they're holding down? If you meant "on click" rather than holding, then check this out: [Javascript smooth scroll WITHOUT the use of jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/javascript-smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery) or [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/smooth-scrolling-vanilla-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks but it would be a fixed element they hold down

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you can accomplish this with [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in combination with [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and [clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp):

```
$('.button').on('mousedown', function() {
    console.log('Start Animate');
    (function smoothSrcroll() {
        console.log(Math.max($('html').scrollTop(), $('body').scrollTop()));
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: Math.max($('html').scrollTop(), $('body').scrollTop()) + 100
        }, 1000, 'linear', function() {
            window.timeout = setTimeout(smoothSrcroll(), 0);
        });
    })();
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    console.log('Stop Animate');
    $('html, body').stop();
    clearTimeout(window.timeout);
});
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/daerik/pen/dORyGj?editors=1111)

I'm targeting `$('html, body')` so that it will work in both Firefox and Chrome. This gets a little tricky because the `animate()` actually runs twice because of the two selectors. To solve this I've used [jQuery.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/). Since Firefox can use the `$('html').scrollTop()` and Chrome uses the `$('body').scrollTop()`, I calculated the increment using [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). The function is self-executing upon completion and uses `clearTimeout()` and `jQuery.stop()` when the mouse is released.

Comment: Works great, thanks! is there a way to make it a little smoother ?

Comment: @ScottHunter There are supplemental scripts that add to easing in the default jQuery library. There are really only 3 settings: linear, swing, and default. You can find scripts that create smoother transitions.