# smoothscroll.init(); not working. Getting error

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I am using a call to `smoothscroll.init()` which looks like this:

```
new WOW().init();
//smoothScroll
smoothScroll.init();
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: smoothScroll is not defined
    at main.js:136
    at main (main.js:140)
    at main.js:144
```

Could anyone help me figure out why?

These are my javascript libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact_me.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: _smoothScroll_ what is it?

Comment: 'smoothScroll is not defined' means that the application has no idea what smoothScroll is, let alone whether is has a method called init().

Comment: Actually I also can't figure it out . I took pre-compiled  javascript libraries

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contact_me.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

Comment: and a main.js file

Comment: @FaizanZahid best to add that to the question by editing it, instead of putting it in a comment

Comment: Did you see my answer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add this to your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second: make sure your path to smoothscroll is correct.

Third: identify each of your html you want to use smoothscroll on with the class `class="smoothScroll"`.

Fourth: the smoothscroll you are using now isn't editable in another javascript directory, it's only used for inside your html, as it already uses the smoothscroll.

EDIT:

If you want to use your own smoothscroll, I'd recommend you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063405/7707749).