# How to make scroll work on nav click with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am looking for way to make page scroll on menu click.

My found place where to go. When I use translateY it work(but ofcouse I can't use it).
I need a scroll I tried to use scrollTop and scrollBy but it doesn't work for me.
What I do wrong?

```js
function scroll(id: number) {
            for (let k = 0; k < sectionsForScroll.length; k++) {
                if (sectionsForScroll[k].dataset.navId == id) {
                    const bigginer = sectionsForScroll[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    console.log( bigginer + 'px  how far we from the start ');
                    const distanceToGo= sectionsForScroll[k].getBoundingClientRect().top;
                    console.log(sectionsForScroll[k].offsetTop);
                    const distanceToScroll = bigginer - distanceToGo;
                    console.log(distanceToGo + ' where we have to go ');
                    console.log(distanceToScroll + ' what the distanse we need to scroll ');
                    main.style.transform = 'translateY(' + distanceToScroll + 'px)';
                    // main.scrollTop=distanceToGo;
                    // window.scrollBy(0, distanceToGo);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window.scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll) will work for you. Here is an example of scrolling 300px after clicking the scroll button.

Before using it you should checkout the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll#Browser_Compatibility) for the smooth option.

```js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", scrollMe);

function scrollMe() {
  window.scroll({
    top: 300,
    left: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
.myDiv {
  background-color: green;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <button id="myButton">Scroll</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Safari doesn't support this way. What is better to use that cover Safari?

Comment: No problem! Safari will still support the scrolling part, but it does not support the "smooth" option. Is that okay?

Comment: Yes, I saw scrolling, but I unfortunetely  I need "smooth".

Comment: this might give you some options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery