# Scroll to dynamically created anchor

Tags: javascript, dynamic, scroll, anchor

In the middle of a long page I have several dynamically created anchors with code like that:

```
// retrieve elements data from the db;
// put them into array $elements_arr
$how_many_elements = count($elements_arr);
for ($i = 1; $i <= how_many_elements; $i ++) {
    echo "<a name='element_" . $i . "'>";
    // some content here
}
```

At the top of the page I have a table with cells containing little images with dynamically created links to the anchors, like this:

```
echo "<table class='tab1'>";
   echo "<tr>";
       for ($a=1; $a<=how_many_elements; $a++) {
           echo "<td class='tdx'>";
               echo "<a href='#element_" . $a . "'><img id='element_img_" . $a . "' name='element_img_" . $a . "'src='path_to_img" . strtolower($image_name_arr[$a-1]) . ".png'></img></a>";
        echo "</td>";
       }
   echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Now, the html links work fine, but I would like to have a smooth scroll to each anchor instead of a jump. How can I do it, with and without JQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smooth scroll without the use of jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063380/smooth-scroll-without-the-use-of-jquery)

Comment: Also, this one might be useful: [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

Comment: using the jQuery second version here: [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link), I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined**. So, where and how I have to define that in my code?

Comment: Forget my last comment. I didn't defined ids but only names for the anchors. Now with ids defined, the code (second JQuery version, for older browsers compatibility) works fine.