# Is TypeScript not using revealing module pattern for classes?

Tags: typescript

Is TypeScript not using revealing module pattern for classes? I expected different result from this code.

```
class Test {

    private privateProperty: any;

    public publicProperty: any;     
}
```

generates this:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() { }
    return Test;
})();
```

I expected something like this:

```
var test = (function(){
    var privateProperty;
    var publicProperty;

    return {
        publicProperty: publicProperty;
    };

})();
```

Comment: No, it’s not. `private`/`public` checking is just done by the compiler and doesn’t influence generated code. (But that’s just a guess. `:)`) Your second example wouldn’t be right, though; it doesn’t even return a function.

Comment: The codegen for `module` is most similar to what you've posted

Comment: @minitech: No, it does not return function, it returns object literal. It is called revealing module pattern. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript

Comment: @epitka: Oh. Well that’s a module, not remotely a constructor.

Comment: @minitech: What do you mean by "not remotely a constructor"?

Comment: @epitka: It’s not a function! There’s no constructor involved, so it couldn’t represent a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RMP is not appropriate for class-based design. `module` does what you want:

```
module myMod {
    var x = 31;
    export var y = x + 15;
}
```

Generates:

```
var myMod;
(function (myMod) {
    var x = 31;
    myMod.y = x + 15;
})(myMod || (myMod = {}));
```

Salient features here:

- Privates are captured with a closure
- Public members are visible as own properties of the object
- The object is created in an IIFE

Comment: I thought that "class" in typescript correlates to what I consider a class in c#, meaning private and public members etc., and module more like a namespace