# Convert namespace to string

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I use the revealing module pattern, and have a namespace `Foo.Bar.Baz`.

How do I convert that to a string `"Foo.Bar.Baz"`?

(If I do `mynamespace.toString()` it yields `"[object Object]"` rather than the desired string.)

Comment: Can you post a simplified example of what it looks like?

Comment: what is `mynamespace`?

Comment: If you only have a reference to the object `Foo.Bar.Baz`, then there is no way to do it. If you have a reference to the root, you could iterate recursively over the namespace to find the object (and keep track of the property names), but this does not sound very efficient.

Comment: @Blender: Of what looks like... the namespace itself? Each part is just a javascript module, with tons of functions, variables, "private" stuff, closures, etc.

Comment: @Jamiec: `var mynamespace = Foo.Bar.Baz;`

Comment: @FelixKling: yes I thought as much. You can go from string to object, but no way I can think of the other way round. **If you could put that in as an answer, I can tick it.**

Comment: \*sigh\* what is `Foo.Bar.Baz`? (This could get long - you need to provide more context and info)

Comment: @Jamiec: the full namespace, see answer to Blender above. But I think FelixKling already answered this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a very simplified verion of the [Revealing module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript):

```
var revealed = function(){
   var a = [1,2,3];
   function abc(){
     return (a[0]*a[1])+a[2];
   }

   return {
      name: 'revealed',
      abcfn: abc
   }
}();
```

You could include an override of `toString` in the revealed object:

```
var revealed = function(){
   var a = [1,2,3];
   function abc(){
     return (a[0]*a[1])+a[2];
   }

   return {
      name: 'revealed',
      abcfn: abc,
      toString = function(){ return "revealed"; }
   }
}();
```

This can then be called using `revealed.toString()` as you first attempted. If your revealed object contains sub objects (namespaces) then each individual `toString` implementation can call the children's `toString` and concatenate with a dot (or whatever is appropriate).