# js - how to namespace this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I'm trying to use namespacing but can;t get it to work.
I've tried wrapping all the code with a mdd = {} and I've tried wrapping everything within `$(document).ready(` with `var MDD = {}` but neither worked.

How can I add a namespacing for this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#categories").sortable({
      revert: true,
      receive: function(evt, ui) {
        ui.item.remove();
        if ( $('#list_to_process li').length == 0) {
          $('#list_to_process').remove();
        }
      }
    });
    $("li.to_process").draggable( {
      connectToSortable: "#categories",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to add to the namespace? I see no exported methods or properties, just 2 function calls ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If organising your code is what you are trying to achieve, I would suggest the following:

- Create your namespace **outside** `$(document).ready` (used [Revealing module pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript) in my example).
- On `$(document).ready` you call your code.

**Example:**

```
$(function(){
    MDD.init();
});

var MDD = function () {
  var init = function () {
    $("#categories").sortable({
      revert: true,
      receive: function(evt, ui) {
        ui.item.remove();
        if ( $('#list_to_process li').length == 0) {
          $('#list_to_process').remove();
        }
      }
    });
    $("li.to_process").draggable( {
      connectToSortable: "#categories",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
  };
  return {
    init : init
  }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's  `.sortable` and `.draggable` calls are methods, not event handlers. As far as I know, they cannot be namespaced.

However, jQuery's `$(document).ready(...` *is* an event handler, so you may be able to namespace it, but only if it works with the `.on` method. Note that I have not tested this, before, but if it is feasible, then the below should work:

```
$(document).on("ready.namespace", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Why anyone would need to namespace the document ready event is another matter.

Comment: @Juhana - I don't know, and I really don't care. It was the question in the OP.