# In JavaScript, what does "return" do in function constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

The following code:

```
function A() {
    this.method_this_outsideReturn = function() {
        console.log('method_this_outsideReturn')
    };
    return {
        method_this_insideReturn: function() {
            console.log('method_this_insideReturn')
        },
    };
}
var a = new A();
console.log(a.method_this_insideReturn()); // This would work.
console.log(a.method_this_outsideReturn()); // This wouldn't work. Warns attri_this_outsideReturn undefined
```

However, after commented out the return:

```
function A() {
    this.method_this_outsideReturn = function() {
        console.log('method_this_outsideReturn')
    };
    /*return {
        method_this_insideReturn: function() {
            console.log('method_this_insideReturn')
        },        
    };*/
}
console.log(a.method_this_outsideReturn()); // This would work now
```

Why is it so? What does return do in constructors? What happens when the return statement is not present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your constructor returns a value, the returned value will be considered as the object created, if you do not have a return statement it will assume it as `return this`

Comment: All answers very useful but this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a return, instead of receiving back and object your receiving back what ever you are returning.

So **a** would not be an object it would be method_this_insideReturn so you will not be able to access your local methods from **a** any more because they don't exist.

Im not sure why you are adding the return but it would be better to make it a local method and then access it.

```
   function A() {
        this.method_this_outsideReturn = function() {
            console.log('method_this_outsideReturn')
        };

        this.method_this_insideReturn: function() {
                console.log('method_this_insideReturn')
            }        

    }

console.log(a.method_this_outsideReturn());

console.log(a.method_this_insideReturn());
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the revealing module pattern see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647397/874927.   You are encapsulating your logic inside a function (function A()).  `return` in a consturctor should just return `this`.  However in your example, it has nothing to do with a constructor it's the same as returning a value from any function in Javascript.

Comment: The linked question is very relevant. Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Every function/method call will have a `return` statement, however if it's not explicitly included it will `return undefined`

Therefore commenting it out in this case would return nothing.

Comment: he is taking about constructor