# Javascript: creation of object from an already instantiated object versus the prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, theory

I have a rather academic question that doesn't particularly apply to anything I'm doing, I just really want to know the answer!

Say we have a simple object definition in the global namespace as such:

```
TestObject = function(){};
```

It has a method added to it's prototype that can be instantiated into a new object itself:

```
TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject = function() {};
```

Instantiate the first object:

```
var myObject = new TestObject();
```

Now my question is this:

How does

```
myObject.myProperty = new myObject.AnotherObject();
```

differ to

```
myObject.myProperty = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
```

Or are they exactly the same?

The difference I see is this: I could use the second method to instantiate objects within the TestObject context without knowing the name of the instantiated object itself, i.e.

```
TestObject.prototype.createAnObject = function() {
    this.anotherProperty = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
}
```

And finally:

What are the implications of using a prototype method to instantiate an object of the same name? Why do this result in an infinite loop? (What actually happens inside..)

```
TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject = function () {
    this.AnotherObject = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
};
myObject.AnotherObject();
```

Yet this does not...

```
TestObject.AnotherObject = function() {};

TestObject.prototype.createAnObject = function() {
    this.AnotherObject = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
};
myObject.createAnObject();
```

...

I have a deep desire to understand the relationships between objects here! Thank you!

The reason I ask these questions is because I want to make something like so where there is a 1:1 relationship between objects:

```
ClientObject = function () {
    this.objectname = "a client class";
}

ClientObject.prototype.loginUser = function(name) {
    this.loggedin = true;
    if (typeof this.User === 'undefined') {
        this.User = new ClientObject.User(name);
    }
}
ClientObject.User = function (name) {
    this.username = name;
}

ClientObject.User.prototype.getProfile = function() {
    return 'user profile';
}

var testClient = new ClientObject();

console.log('testClient.User = ' + (typeof testClient.User)); // should not exist
testClient.loginUser('Bob'); // should login 'bob'
console.log('testClient.User = ' + (typeof testClient.User)); // should exist now Bob is logged in
console.log(testClient.User.username); // should be bob
testClient.loginUser('Tom'); // should not do anything as User object already created
console.log(testClient.User.username); // bob still
console.log(testClient.User.getProfile()); // new functionality available
```

I am just not sure if I'm breaking any best practises or conventions here unwittingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> myObject.myProperty = new myObject.AnotherObject();
>
> differ to
>
> myObject.myProperty = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();

There's no difference at all.  Remember, objects in JavaScript have a prototype chain.  When you call `new myObject.AnotherObject();` the engine will first check for a `AnotherObject` on `myObject` itself.  Failing to find it, it will check on `myObject`'s prototype, which it will find.  The second version

```
myObject.myProperty = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
```

Just goes right to the place where `AnotherObject` is defined.

---

```
TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject = function () {
    this.AnotherObject = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
}
myObject.AnotherObject();
```

Just walk through the code.  When you say: `myObject.AnotherObject();`, `AnotherObject` will be called, with `this` set to `myObject`.  The first line of that will attempt to create a new property on `myObject` (which is `this`) by setting it to the result of

```
new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
```

which will then re-enter the very same `AnotherObject` function, but this time with `this` set to a new object whose prototype is set to `TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject`'s prototype.  And so on *ad infinitum*

---

Finally,

```
TestObject.prototype.createAnObject = function() {
    this.AnotherObject = new TestObject.prototype.AnotherObject();
}
myObject.createAnObject();
```

Will **not** cause an infinite loop, so far as I can tell, and as far as I can test: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2w68B/)

Basically, `createAnObject` will enter with `this` set to `myObject`.  Inside of which a brand new property called `AnotherObject` will be created on myObject, which will be set to a new invocation of the `AnotherObject` **function** you previously set up.

Note that after this call is made, the `AnotherObject` **function** will *still exist*, **but**, it will be **shadowed** by the `AnotherObject` *property* you just created.  So now you'll never ever be able to say

```
var f = new myObject.AnotherObject()
```

Because you now have a `AnotherObject` **property** sitting right on myObject, which will be found and returned before anything on the prototype is ever checked.

Well, I mean, you could always say `delete myObject.AnotherObject` and remove that property from the object, which would then open you up to the `AnotherObject` being found on the prototype, but really, you should avoid name conflicts like this to begin with.

---

Regarding your last bit of code

A) Why not make `User` its **own** function?
B) Why not set up `this.User = new ...()` right in the ClientObject constructor function?  That way you wouldn't need the `undefined` check
C) `ClientObject` should be defined as

```
function ClientObject(){...`
```

the you have it now seems to be creating an implicit global.

Comment: I appreciate the response so far, I guess the setup was to find out whether my method of referencing objects within objects using the prototype definition is valid.

Comment: It's valid more of less, but you're doing some strange things that would make debugging a nightmare - like the last part of my answer, coming shortly.

Comment: The reason I have structured the last bit of code as displayed is because I want to have a bunch of self contained objects. For example, if I am writing an API to interact with a whole bunch of backend services, I'd like to split them into modules in the same context namespace and store state inside a main object. It does not make sense for a user object to exist before one is "logged in", as certain functionality should not be available unless a user is logged in.

Comment: @Ross - the revealing module pattern might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript

Comment: Its time for you to consider using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for modularity and other MVC frameworks like [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [canjs](http://canjs.com/), etc... Good luck!

Comment: @ManKum : require.js is great when building an app but I have found it very confusing when building an API/library that will be consumed by a javascript application. There is no documentation on how to configure it as such, but I do use require.js for my test-suite and expose my library with a define regardless.

Comment: One final note, my intention in the last bit is to create an implicit global. It would be a library that is pulled into a javascript app to expose an object at the global level which houses all the functionality to interact with backend web services. For example: var myClient = new ClientObject(); myClient.loginUser(userid); myClient.User.getProfile();

Comment: Could anyone please reevaluate the last section of code? I've updated it to make my intentions clear. ClientObject would be my library, the code underneath is a consumer (a javascript web app for example). I want to make certain functionality available based on internal state, this seems like a good way to manage it.

Comment: A demonstration of the prototype chaining described here, that I think illustrates a lot about how prototypes work in Javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/MWDrK/