# difference between those 2 way to define a method in a javascript class

Tags: javascript, methods

I have the following class:

```
var myclass = (function(){
   var b={};

   b.method1 = function(){
       console.log("method1");
   };

   b.method2 = function class2(){
       console.log("method2");
   };

   return b;
}());
```

Is there any difference between these methods other than that `method1` is anonymous functions assigned to method1 and `method2` is a named function?

I usually use the method1 way but just discover method2 for method declaration.

And are there any advantages to use one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Revealing module pattern in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript)

Comment: method2 shows "class2" in an error log, but method1 shows "anonymous", which do you find more helpful?

Comment: Just a side note: You could use `this` instead of `var b`, and get rid of the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

For a named function expression(method2) you can call the function within itself by its name.

```
b.method2 = function class2(){
   console.log("method2");
   if (somecondition){
       var something = new class2();
   }
};
```

Comment: Actually, the name can be used not only to call the function, but also to refer to itself in a more general way.

Answer (score 0):

Functional this is nearly the same. On some Browsers you can see a difference if you call `console.log( b.method1, b.method2 )` because the second one has a name. 
There is a variety of articles on this topic here. This is one of them: [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-expression-vs-declaration-in-javascrip)

Answer (score 0):

A function name in JavaScipt is basically a variable, so you can reuse it. This means you can use `class2` within your self-executing function without calling `b.method2`. Since your self-executing function returns your `b` Object, you can't use `class2` outside.