# javascript issue with namespace, "this" and a library

Tags: javascript, namespaces, scope, queue, javascript-namespaces

I'm building a visualization page (with `dc.js`) for which I decided to make the jump and gather it all into a single namespace. Coming from Python's simplicity, crashing against JavaScript's scope madness has been tough enough, so please bear with me.

I have a general JS structure as follows:

```
var NamespaceClass = function() {

    this.var0 = "something";
    this.var1 = dc.SomeChartClass("#some-css-selector");

    this.setup = function(error, config, dataset) {
        console.log("Inside setup:", this);
        this.var2 = this.process_data(dataset);
        // Do some more stuff...
    }

    this.process_data = function(data) {
        var whatever;
        //Do stuff with "data"...
        return whatever;
    }

    this.start = function() {
        console.log("Inside start:", this);
        var q;

        q = queue().defer(d3.json, "config.json")
                   .defer(d3.csv, "data.csv");
        q.await(this.setup);
    }
}

var MyNamespace = new NamespaceClass();
MyNamespace.start();
```

where `queue` is [Mike Bostock's queue lib](https://github.com/mbostock/queue) for asynchronous file queueing. When I try to test the script, I get in the console:

```
Inside start: Object { var0 = "something", var1={...}, more...}
Inside setup: Window testpage.html
TypeError: this.process_data is not a function
```

So, invoking `setup` from `q.await` makes it loose the object's scope (or whatever this is called in JavaScript...). How can I avoid this? I have also tried using a proxy object like:

```
    this.start = function() {
        console.log("Inside start:", this);
        var q, proxy;

        q = queue().defer(d3.json, "config.json")
                   .defer(d3.csv, "data.csv");
        proxy = this.setup;
        q.await(proxy);
    }
```

to no avail!

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but there is no need to create a class to have a namespace. A simple object will do, you can initialize it with an IIFE to have all your variables scoped so they don't pollute the global scope.

Comment: This has been the only way so far that has allowed me to perform inter-class method calls (like `this.fun1` calling `this.fun2`). But it's rather tedious using `this.` every time. Would you care to point to me to some examples of what you're suggesting?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5647397/1669279) has an example.

Comment: I tried that way, but it wouldn't allow me to have class functions (methods) call other methods on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by how you call the function that contains it. You have no control over how the `setup` function is called, since it is called inside the `q.await` function.

When you do `q.await(this.setup)`, you pass a reference to the function setup, but "lose" any connection to your namespace. You need to bind the function to the namespace for it to have the proper `this` value:

```
q.await(this.setup.bind(this));
```

Even better, since all your functions work only if `this` is the namespace, you should bind them to the namespace like this:

```
this.start = function() {
  // body
}.bind(this);

// usage:
q.await(this.setup);
```

And now wherever you pass them, they will have the correct `this` inside.

Note: in this situation, `bind` works something like this:

```
this.start = function() {
    var namespace = this;

    q.await(function(){ namespace.setup(); });
}
```

Comment: I had to use `.bind(namespace)` (where `namespace` is as per your last example) for anonymous functions declared within fluent methods (like those of `dc.js`) inside of class methods.