# Scope of variables in module pattern

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how I can touch/change/increment my privately scoped variable x in the following script.  I'm using the Module pattern here, and thought I could reach into and set the private variables from a public return module declared property or method, but nothing I'm trying is working.  Related:  when do you declare a new instance of func vs. accessing func as a static delcared variable?

```js
    var func = (function() {
      var x = 1;
      var squareX = function() {
        return x * x;
      };
      var addOne = function() {
        x++;
      }
      return {
        X: x,
        Xq: squareX,
        AddOne: addOne
      };
    });

    func().X = 9; // expecting privately scoped x = 9
    func().AddOne(); // expecting privately scoped x = 10
    document.write(func().Xq()); // expecting 100 actual = 1
```

Comment: You need to add a setter.

Comment: `X` is not `x`. You've set `X:x` which is just copying the current value of `x` into `X`. They are not connected in anyway. You need a setter function.

Comment: Your `func()` does not have a method or property called `X`.

Comment: @JonathanM huh? Sure it does.

Comment: Also, every time you do `func()` you are creating a new function with a completely separate `x`. Presumably you intended to use an IIFE?

Answer (score 3):

The point of the module pattern is to create a **persistent**, private scope which is invisible from the outside. Unfortunately, every time you call `func`, you're creating a *new* scope (with new return functions and their closures), so all of your operations are discarded afterwards.

Instead of calling `func` multiple times, just do it once to setup the "module" (you can even do this immediately, with an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)), and then perform operations on the result.

```js
var func = function() {
  var x = 1; // this is the private variable

  var squareX = function() {
    return x * x;
  };
  var addOne = function() {
    x++;
  };

  return {
    // Note, you can't just do "X: x,"
    // since that will just create a copy;
    // you have to use properties
    get X() { return x; },
    set X(val) { x = val; },

    Xq: squareX,
    AddOne: addOne
  };
};

var funcModule = func();
funcModule.X = 9;
funcModule.AddOne();
document.write(funcModule.Xq());
```

Note that the reason you need an explicit getter and setter for the `X` module property is because you need to be able to modify the inner (hidden) variable `x`. Properties are available in all modern browsers, including IE9+. If you're working in IE8 or below, you'll need to define explicit `getX` and `setX` methods, and call them directly (you won't just be able to do `funcModule.X = 5`).

Comment: OK, didn't realize that get; set; were part of the javascript language (always impressed with the language as I learn more).  In the other example Matt demonstrates that you can write a getter as a function too, so that's cool.

Answer (score 2):

You need a setter, and you need an IIFE:

```js
var func = (function() {
  var x = 1;
  var squareX = function() {
    return x * x;
  };
  var addOne = function() {
    x++;
  }
  return {
    X: function(value) {
      if (value !== undefined) {
        x = value;
      }
      return x;    // we can use this as a getter too!
    },
    Xq: squareX,
    AddOne: addOne
  };
})(); // <-- this actually runs the function - this makes it an IIFE

document.write("X is " + func.X() + "</br>");

func.X(9); // expecting privately scoped x = 9

document.write("now X is " + func.X() + "</br>");

func.AddOne(); // expecting privately scoped x = 10

document.write("now X is " + func.X() + "</br>");

document.write(func.Xq()); // expecting 100 actual = 100
```

Comment: *immediately invoked function expression*

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Revealing Module Pattern to hide your private instance variable. When using that pattern, you **must** use a setter of some kind to change your private instance variable. Here is another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521069/global-variables-shared-amongst-javascript-modules/23541293#23541293) where someone else was having the same problem.

I don't recommend that you use the Revealing Module Pattern. In fact, I just gave a [talk](http://slides.com/i-linkuo/the-revealing-module-is-an-anti-pattern#/) at [NationJS 2014](http://nationjs.com/) titled "The Revealing Module is an Anti-Pattern".