# How do you return an object from a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and I would greatly appreciate your help. I would like to us higher order functions and callbacks if possible.

**Task**

1. Declare these local variables and make them equal to the appropriate information, **firstName, LastName, linkedIn, phone, city**.
2. Using string concatenation, make a local variable **fullName** equal to your first and last names separated by a space.
3. Make a local variable **linkedIn**, a string which is a link to your LinkedIn profile.
4. Make a local variable **info** which is an array containing your **fullName**, **linkedIn**, **phone**, and **city** variables, in that order.
5. Make a local variable **education** which is an array containing the name of your college/university, field of study, an integer which is your year of (anticipated) graduation. Make sure it's in that order.
6. Define a function **createApp** which takes your info and education as arguments in that order. This should return an object containing 2 keys. The key names must be the same as your variable names. Set the values of these keys to the corresponding arguments.

**Steps 1-5:**
Created local variables.

```
 (function person() {
   var firstName = "Rob",
   lastName = "Johnson",
   fullName = firstName + ", " + lastName,
   linkedIn = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/robjohnson',
   phone = 3105559288,
   city = 'Los Angeles',
   info = [firstName, linkedIn, phone, city],
   education = ['UWRock','Generals','2017'];
 })();
```

**step 6.** 
return an object containing 2 keys. The key names must be the same as your variable names. Set the values of these keys to the corresponding arguments.  I have no idea, I assume this should be dynamic not hard coded.

```
function createApp(info, education){
   var myObj = {}; 
   return(myObj);
};
```

I think I'm suppose to return something like this using a callback:

```
myObj {
  info:'Rob', 
  education: ['UWRock','Generals','2017']
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496076/javascript-return-with-colon will help you

Comment: Could you write down a code for your example? var resultObject = {... ? It is not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: @Trike, I updated the question and gave the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
function list () { 
  var firstName = "Rob",
      lastName = "Johnson",
      fullName = firstName + ", " + lastName,
      linkedIn = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/robjohnson',
      phone = 3105559288,
      city = 'Los Angeles',
      info = [firstName, linkedIn, phone, city],
      education = ['UWRock','Generals','2017'];

  createApp(info,education);

}

function createApp(info, education){
  var emptyObj = {},
      strArr = ['info','education'],
      myArray = [info, education];

      for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        emptyObj[strArr[i]] = myArray[i];
      }

   console.log(emptyObj);

}

list();
```

The results are

```
[ Object ] {
 education: ["UWRock", "Generals", "2017"],
 info: ["Rob", "https://www.linkedin.com/in/robjohnson", 3105559288,"Los Angeles"]
}
```

I'm trying to find a better approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have following function

```
var GraphicalFilters = (function() {
    var SelectedFilters = {};     
    return {
        initializaAllFilters: function(value1,value2) {
                    SelectedFilters = {};
                    SelectedFilters.value1 = value1;
                    SelectedFilters.value2 = value2;
        },
        getAllFilters: function() {
            return SelectedFilters;
        }
    };
})();
```

You can get object via following:

```
GraphicalFilters.initializaAllFilters(1,2);
var $filters = GraphicalFilters.getAllFilters();
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't follow the guidelines from the challenge.  I have to create a function with two arguments first.  Thank you though!