# Function inside object is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my object

```
var Controller = (function () {
    var self = this;
    self.get = function (req, res) {
        res.send({
            success: 'you got me'
        });
    }
    return self;
})()
module.exports = Controller;
```

and below is how i am trying to pass parameters to the get function from another document.

```
var Controller = require('../Controller.js');
Controller.get(arg1, arg2);
```

However nodejs throws 'TypeError: Controller.get is not a function', what am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: `BackgammonController` is not the same as `Controller`

Comment: Also, to use `this` properly, the function has to be called with `new`.

Comment: @thefourtheye that was my mistake forgot to change that. Edited my question now. That's not the case for my error. :)

Comment: Have you considered using [revealing module pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript)?

Comment: @thefourtheye: It's in a NodeJS module, there's no need for that pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with that code, but it will not cause the `TypeError: Controller.get is not a function` you describe.

The way you're calling your anonymous function that creates `Controller` means that `this` within it will be the global object (loose mode) or `undefined` (strict mode). Let's assume loose mode as you haven't said you're getting an error assigning `get` to `undefined`. That means you're creating a **global** function called `get`. It also means that `Controller` returns the global object.

Neither of those is a good thing. :-)

If you want to export an object with a `get` function, you don't need to do anything nearly so complicated:

```
var Controller = {
    get: function (req, res) {
        res.send({
            success: 'you got me'
        });
    }
};
module.exports = Controller;
```

Or perhaps

```
function get() {
    res.send({
        success: 'you got me'
    });
}

module.exports = { get: get };
```

Since this is in the context of a NodeJS module, that doesn't define a global function (modules are called in a private scope).

---

**Or**, if you meant `Controller` to be a *constructor*, then you need to call it via `new` and reorganize it slightly:

```
function Controller() {
    var self = this; // If you need it for something, you don't in your example
    self.get = function get() {
        res.send({
            success: 'you got me'
        });
    };
}

module.exports = Controller;
```

then use it via `new`:

```
var Controller = require('./.Controller.js');

var c = new Controller();
c.get("foo", "bar");
```

---

It's also probably worth pointing out that `require('../Controller.js')` uses the `Controller.js` file from the *parent* directory, not the current directory. Just in case that wasn't on purpose and you're getting the `TypeError: Controller.get is not a function` because you're getting the wrong file.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I will try now and respond.

Comment: Thanks i've converted my code as your first suggestion and it works now.