# Mocking different log levels on Azure Function context with jest in javascript

Tags: javascript, azure

I have been playing around with testing my Azure Functions, but I am unable to mock the context log function.

For example I have the following Azure Function:

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  if (req.query.isGood) {
    context.log("Goooood!!!")
    context.res = {
      body: {
        message: "This is good!"
      }
    };
  } else {
    context.log.error("Not gooood!!!")
    context.res = {
      status: 404,
      body: {
        message: "This is not good!"
      }
    };
  }
}
```

So I want to check the amount of times a certain log occured, for example 'log.error' occured once and 'log' occured twice, but I am unable to mock this.

I tried a couple of combinations like:

```js
log: {
      "": jest.fn(),
      "error": jest.fn()
}
```

At this point I'm clueless on how to mock these functions, and am wondering if it is even possible? And how do you create these kind of functions?

Answer (score 5):

In order to do this you need to [create a closure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42177379/javascript-object-with-default-function-and-other-functions) that is immediately invoked. Inside that function, create your default and then add to it the additional methods. In Typescript, you need to cast `jest.fn()` to the any type to get around type checking.

```
log: (function() { 
    let main = <any>jest.fn((message) => message) ;

    let info = jest.fn((message) => message); 
    main.info = info;

    return main;
})()
```

Once you are back in your test, this should then behave as expected:

```
test ('log test', () => {
    context.log("foo");
    context.log.info("bar");

    expect(context.log.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual("foo");
    expect(context.log.info.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual("bar");
});
```

Comment: Some eslint configurations may throw errors when `<any>` is used. I over came this with `const main = () => jest.fn((message) => message)`