# implement interface that has anonymous call signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an instance of this interface

```
interface Logger {
  (...args: any[]): void;
  error(...args: any[]): void;
  warn(...args: any[]): void;
  info(...args: any[]): void;
  verbose(...args: any[]): void;
}
```

i.e it has to be both callable and it has to be possible to access the properties.

```
const log: Logger = ...implementation //this is what I am looking for
log('asd') // this should work
log.error('foo') // this should work
```

How do I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Did you change Object.prototype.valueOf() native implementation in your logger?

Comment: It's not my logger, it is the "@azure/functions" logger. I am just trying to mock the implementation for my tests

Comment: Could you please provide link to docs ?

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732004/mocking-different-log-levels-on-azure-function-context-with-jest-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is the same as for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61732004/mocking-different-log-levels-on-azure-function-context-with-jest-in-javascript). Credit to [@SamaraSoucy-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11002318/samarasoucy-msft)

You implement it by creating a closure that invokes immediately. Define the main method and add properties to it. Example below.

```js
const log = (function () {
  let main = function () { console.log(...arguments); }
  main.info = function () { console.log(...arguments); };
  main.error = function () { console.log(...arguments); };
  //...other methods

  return main;

})();


log('asd')
log.info('this is info')
log.error('this is error')
```